# How to get data from URL using Windows and C?

Tags: c, windows, url

To open a URL in the user's web browser is easy enough:

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", url, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

What do I call instead to retrieve data from a website using a given URL? On the Mac, I'd use:

```
URLSimpleDownload(url, NULL, newDataH, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

It stores in the newDataH handle the data retrieved from url. Easy enough. Is there an equivalent for this on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `InternetReadFile` function in [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Here is a nice list of common functions in that API: [Common functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383949%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

just use the [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) library and your problem is solved for every platform on earth

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See the [Windows HTTP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation at MSDN.