# How can I connect to an FTP with C?

Tags: c, windows, ftp

Well, I'm trying to do a simple script to check any updates in an application. To check this, the most simple way I found is to connect to the FTP (where have a file which says the last update) and compares X file with a Y file. If the Y file is outdated, the script should run an installer/updater. Can I do it with C? I mean, can I connect to an FTP using C?
I research but nothing helpful was found.

At least, why C? I actually don't know. Part cause it is the language that I have more affinity, part cause I think it's clean, I dunno. Just intuition. haha.

Hope I have been clear.

PS: Working on Windows.

Comment: I would say HTTP is much simpler than FTP? [How to get data from URL using Windows and C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347568/how-to-get-data-from-url-using-windows-and-c)

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ wonder what kind of "research" you did..

Comment: I'll try that, Blindy.

Comment: FTP is a massive pain to work with. Avoid it if at all possible. As Alex K suggests, HTTP is almost certainly a better choice.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I'm trying to keep the original code of the other side. Thanks, btw. :)

Comment: yes you can, first of all you should know socket programming and then make a research on FTP protocol. Then, you are good to go

Comment: It might be easier to write a script/batch file, and then use system() to run it from C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found another way to do this with a Batch File. I'm connecting to the FTP using the script (ftp -s:commands.txt ip.ftp) and then I use a comparation to check the differences. The rest was simple. Thank you all.